# How to make that all permalinks would open in a new window?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

Where should I amend to make this happen? I should add somewhere target="blank_"

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the link tag of course:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">link title</a>
```

but it is `_blank` and not `blank_`

Comment: I do not need a custom text because the permalink is creating a link. My code <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>  but apparently, this is not working